# $P(X^2 - 12X+35 \gt 0)$

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the probability of the random variable above.

(Where $X$ is a real number from the interval $[2,10]$ with a density function of the form:
$f(x) = x/48$ )

*Sorry for the messy equations as I do not know how to use LaTex using codecogs)

Comment: Learn how to render here:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $Y=X^2-12X+35=(X-5)(X-7)$. Then $Y$  is positive if $X\gt 7$ **or** $X\lt 5$.  Calculate $\Pr(X\gt 7)$, and $\Pr(X\lt 5)$, and add.

Comment: How do you get X>7 or X<5 from (X-5)(X-7)?

Comment: A product $ab$ is $\gt 0$ if $a$ and $b$ are both positive or both negative. $X-5$ and $X-7$ are both positive if $X\gt 7$. They are both negative if $X\lt 5$.